# Limit of the sequence given by $x_{n+1}=x_n-x_n^{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Let , $x_1 \in (0,1)$ be a real number. For $n>1$ define $x_{n+1}=x_n-x_n^{n+1}$. Then prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists.

We have to prove that the given sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent. So we have to show that $\{x_n\}$ is monotone and bounded.

I proved that the sequence is monotone decreasing. But I'm unable to show that it is bounded below. How can I show it ?

Any other way to prove that the limit exists ?

Comment: $0 \le x \le 1 \implies 0 \le x^n \le x\,$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit of $(x_n)$ with $0&lt;x_1&lt;1$ and $x_{n + 1} = x_n - x_n^{n + 1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186293/limit-of-x-n-with-0x-11-and-x-n-1-x-n-x-nn-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We show by induction that $x_n \in (0,1)$ for all $n$:

The case $n=1$ is clear.

Now let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x_n \in (0,1)$

Then: $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n^n)$. From  $x_n \in (0,1)$ we get  $x_n^n \in (0,1)$ and therefore  $1-x_n^n \in (0,1)$.

Consequence:  $x_{n+1} \in (0,1)$.