# Find the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n-x_n^{n+1}$ where $0<x_1<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n-x_n^{n+1}$ where $0<x_1<1$.

I think zero is the limit but how do I  prove that? I prove that sequence is monotone decreasing and bounded so convergent.

Comment: I don't think it always goes to zero. If you set $x_1 = 0.5$, for example ...

Comment: @Matti P, that means for different $x_1$, limit is different.

Comment: Yes. I would recommend you try some values and try to come up with a theory of what the limit is.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the recursive sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is strictly decreasing and positive so it has a non negative limit $L(x_1)$. However $L(x_1)$ is always positive.

To see this, first note that $x_2=x_1-x_1^2\in (0,1/4]$. Moroever, for $n\geq 2$,
$$x_n=x_2+\sum_{k=3}^n(x_k-x_{k-1})=x_2-\sum_{k=3}^nx_{k-1}^k\geq  x_2-\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}x_{2}^k=x_2-\frac{x_2^3}{1-x_2}$$
Hence
$$L(x_1)\geq  x_2-\frac{x_2^3}{1-x_2}=\frac{x_2(1-(x_2+x_2^2))}{1-x_2}\geq \frac{11 x_2}{12}=\frac{11 x_1(1-x_1)}{12}>0.$$

Comment: That should be $\frac{x_1 - 2 x_1^2}{1-x_1}$, so $> 0$ for $x \in (0,1/2)$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Also, as soon as you have $0 < x_m < 1/2$, for $n > m$ you get, for $n > m$, $x_n > x_m - \frac{x_m^{m+1}}{1-x_m} > 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I agree!

Comment: We do not claim this and we do not need it in this approach. But, either there is, and then RI's remark shows that $L(x_1)>0$, or there is not, and then $L(x_1)\geqslant\frac12$. In both cases, $L(x_1)>0$.

Comment: @Did See my re-edited answer. Do you agree?

Comment: Indeed, nice shortcut.

Comment: @Did Your comments helped me to improve my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, @Did should know this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/186333/42969 :)

Comment: @MartinR Almost six years ago... Amply enough time to forget it. :-)

Comment: @Did: Instantly found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3Dx_n-x_n%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%24&p=1) :-)

Comment: Wow, "Ewige Wiederkunft" strikes again! (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return)